# JQuery not returning any information for the JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getjson

I am working on S3. In a bucket i have a browser.json file, jquery.js, and index.html. In my index.html I am writing a script that reads my JSON file. Here is what my code looks like...

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $.getJSON('https://s3.amazonaws.com/plxscreenshots/browser.json', function(data) {
            alert(data.date)
        });
    </script>
    <p> I hope this works!</p>
</body>
```

I am still pretty new to html/javascript but I feel like this should be working and it is not, any suggestions?

Comment: Rule 1 when JavaScript doesn't work: **Look at the error console**. You have this error: *XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/plxscreenshots/browser.json. Origin http://run.jsbin.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*

Comment: if I request the file, I only get the date. Try this: `alert(data.Date)`

Comment: The JSON it is sending back does not appear to be properly formatted and does not contain a `value1` property, just a `date`.

Comment: You are getting this: <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>0813367144E81B13</RequestId>
<HostId>
aL2Nd7MbNlw1nw3bjPbXS/W9MrG/0NeHaBiTXCnGzCbBicH/M2lyoRF2WV53M88s
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Have u checked the MIME type allowed in your IIS manager.. I had an issue and this resolved it

Comment: @quentin: I dont think this is a duplicate. Looks perfectly valid to me. Yes the info provided is minimal and there is scope for improvement on that front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a couple of issues which are going on here.

1. First you have the same-origins problem, [which has been addressed elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy),
2. Second, you have poorly formatted JSON in your JSON file, and
3. third you don't have a value1 property.

I would expect your JSON file to look more like this:

```
{"date": "2013-07-19", "value1": 5678 }
```

Notice how both the keys *and* the date is quoted? In JSON, you have to quote anything which isn't a number, an object (`[]` and `{}`), or a boolean (`true` or `false`). Also notice how there is no trailing comma?

The first two problems will cause an error before you even get feedback and because you have no error handler, it will fail silently (though hopefully you're at least seeing an error in your JavaScript console). You can make this a little easier by adding `.error(function(a) { alert("error"); console.log(e); })` to the end of your function. Something like:

```js
$.getJSON(<my-url>, function(data) {
     alert(data.value1)
}).error(function(a) { alert("error"); console.log(e);});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The same-origin domain policy will not allow you to load from a file on a different domain using AJax.

2) Your file doesn't contain JSON. It contains:

```
{date : 2013-07-19 , }
```

JSON would look like:

```
{"date": "2013-07-19"}
```